# Android ImagePicker Library Select Videos Only (Exclude Images)

Tags: android

I implemented the following ImagePicker library from  https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker however I am not sure how I can exclude images and only be able to select videos.

The library has a feature to exclude images `.exclude(images) // exclude anything that in image.getPath()` but not quite clear what `images` should be initialized as to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the ImagePicker properties you will find a onlyVideo(true) property you can use for this case.
So you just can enable it this way in your ImagePicker instance.

Comment: thank you so much, where can I find a complete set of these properties you are referring to, my only reference was the usage manual (which didn't include that option)

Comment: It looks like a pretty new commit and it's not in their documentation, I just went through the implementation and found it... https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker/blob/master/imagepicker/src/main/java/com/esafirm/imagepicker/features/ImagePicker.java#L166

Answer (score 0):

why you are going for library take advantage of native in Built Solution for picking Image.

Code Like in In-Built That

**Note: This Method Is Work On Android 8 or Above Version**

Also, Go For My Github Repo For show My Project Work
https://github.com/axarlotwala/CafeDelear

// using intent open file chooser option

```
private void ShowFileChooser() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

}
```

// show selected and path image in imageview

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    PATH = data.getData();

    try {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),PATH);
        cat_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        tv_path.setText("Path : " .concat(GetPath(PATH)));


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

//get correct path of image
private String GetPath(Uri uri){

    String result;
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
    if (cursor == null){
        result = uri.getPath();
    }else {

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        result = cursor.getString(id);
        cursor.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```